# Tinymce contenteditable and backspace button

Tags: tinymce

I use tinyMCE and this tag inserting as dynamically by button.

`<span class="_pElement" contenteditable="false">variable</span>`

When i select this tag on editor and press backspace button, the page return back page. It should delete this tag when press backspace button.

Answer (score 0):

You should [focus](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.focus) the editor right after you inserted the span:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').focus();
```

Comment: yes, I focus but then when i click inserted element and press backspace, page return back

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this? so i will be able to check this out myself